# HTML Fonts & Other Elements Double Rendering

Tags: html, ios, css, fonts

This is a little weird... I coded some web pages for a client recently.  Everything looks great on most browsers, but on his iPad, he's seeing what he called "fuzzy fonts."  Looking at his screenshot, it's clear the font is rendering twice, with the second rendition offset by two pixels.  This is how it looks on his iPad:

[image]

This is how it looks (and *should* look) on my PC:

[image]

Looking more closely at the web page, it's not just fonts that exhibit this issue.  Borders around a div, for example, are also doubled.

I'm pretty sure I've seen this phenomenon before, but haven't been able to track it down.  I figure it's got to be a device issue, but I'd still like to find solution if possible.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If it’s a device issue, it’s off-topic here. If it’s something in your code, you need to post code that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: Yes, well that's the problem, isn't it?  If I could reproduce it, it would be much easier to debug.  I was hoping someone else had seen this and could comment.  Perhaps calling it a "device issue" was imprecise on my part; I'd guess it's most likely a specific OS issue.  Thanks for your input though.